# Spring Pet Clinic Enhancement Using @Formula

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I added a way to charge owners for a visit and mark which visits have been paid to the age-old Spring Pet Clinic project. Now I am looking to make a list of owners that are past due in their accounts. The problem I have run into is the owners table:

```
CREATE TABLE owners (
  id         INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(30),
  last_name  VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(30),
  address    VARCHAR(255),
  city       VARCHAR(80),
  telephone  VARCHAR(20)
);
```

has nothing to do with the visits table:

```
CREATE TABLE visits (
  id          INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  pet_id      INTEGER NOT NULL,
  visit_date  DATE,
  description VARCHAR(255),
  price       NUMERIC(5,2),
  payment_due DATE,
  billed      BOOLEAN,
  paid        BOOLEAN
);
```

where the prices and due dates are kept. If I could use a `@Formula` annotation, I think I would be all set, but when I try run a SQL query from the `Owner` class like so:

```
@Formula("(SELECT MAX(price) FROM visits)")
private int balance;
```

I get an error:

```
WARN  SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: -5501, SQLState: 42501
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper - user lacks privilege or object not found: OWNER0_.PRICE
WARN  warn - Handler execution resulted in exception: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement;...
```

I would like to do a complicated SQL statement, but I cannot even get the simple one above to work. Any help just to get a @Function annotation working (or an alternate solution) would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to specify where `price` is coming from, so like `@Formula("(SELECT MAX(v.price) FROM visits v)")`

Comment: If you notice in your error message it says `user lacks privilege or object not found: OWNER0_.PRICE` so its looking in the Owner table for the column `price` you need to specify exactly what table price is coming from as the query in `@Formula` is currently not specifying it.  My guess is that although the Owner table is not specified in the query, hibernate is doing some under the hood magic to make column names default to that table.  So I would try explicitly saying where price comes from, see if the error changes and go from there.

Comment: I hadn't thought about giving the table an alias. I will be sure to accept your answer if it works. I will try it first thing tomorrow.

Comment: Yea you could also just do `visits.price` probably, its just a habit of mine to lessen the table name down to a character or two.  Most of the table names I usually work with are like 20-40 characters long 0.0